# OpenSSL in php and curl not update after upgrading OpenSSL in linux

Tags: php, ssl, curl, redhat

My PHP program worked fine until several days ago. I suddenly got an error "SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure" from using curl in my php program. I searched on the net and found it may be because my openssl is too old (0.9.8e) and not support the TLS.

I tried "yum update openssl" but it doesn't help as the Openssl hasn't been upgraded and is still 0.9.8e. So, I downloaded and installed a newer version (1.0.2j) from the net. And now, it does displays the new version number by the command "openssl version", but it still displays the old version number by phpinfo() and "curl -V". And of course, it still shows the SSL error while running the php program.

I am very new in server setting. How can I update openssl version in php and curl?

Comment: Server issue not s programming one.

Comment: You must recompile all the binaries which depend on the old SSL version. It might be simpler to update your server since given how old the OpenSSL is the rest of the software is probably as old and maybe not supported either.

Comment: Updating the server seems not an option for me. How can I recompile the php and curl?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update php itself, as it comes with ssl compiled in. The libssl on the system is not used by php. It might also be encapsulated in the php-curl package.

Comment: I have upgrade the php from 5.4 to 5.5, but the version of openssl and SSL verion of curl shown in the phpinfo() still haven't changed. How can I update the php-curl package?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem by "downloading and installing" the latest version of OpenSSL, cUrl and PHP, and setting the configure for the new paths of OpenSSL and cUrl for PHP.